Polars: Remove substring from column based on another column
Is there any Polars-based optimization that can be applied to the apply-lambda methodology in this post Remove substring from column based on another column ?
In the polars dataframe below, how could we remove the "_sub" substrings based on the value of sub?
import polars as pl

pl.DataFrame(
    {"origin": ["id1_COUNTRY", "id2_NAME"],
     "sub": ["COUNTRY", "NAME"]}
)

shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ origin      ┆ sub     │
│ ---         ┆ ---     │
│ str         ┆ str     │
╞═════════════╪═════════╡
│ id1_COUNTRY ┆ COUNTRY │
│ id2_NAME    ┆ NAME    │
└─────────────┴─────────┘

The expected output should look like:
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────┬─────────┬─────┐
│ origin      ┆ sub     ┆ out │
│ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ --- │
│ str         ┆ str     ┆ str │
╞═════════════╪═════════╪═════╡
│ id1_COUNTRY ┆ COUNTRY ┆ id1 │
│ id2_NAME    ┆ NAME    ┆ id2 │
└─────────────┴─────────┴─────┘


In the given example, you are only stripping the suffix.

str.strip_suffix()

df.with_columns(
   out = pl.col("origin").str.strip_suffix("_" + pl.col("sub"))
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────┬─────────┬─────┐
│ origin      ┆ sub     ┆ out │
│ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ --- │
│ str         ┆ str     ┆ str │
╞═════════════╪═════════╪═════╡
│ id1_COUNTRY ┆ COUNTRY ┆ id1 │
│ id2_NAME    ┆ NAME    ┆ id2 │
└─────────────┴─────────┴─────┘

.replace_many() can be used for a general "substring" replacement.
df.with_columns(
   out = (pl.col("origin") + "_other")
            .str.replace_many("_" + pl.col("sub"), "")
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ origin      ┆ sub     ┆ out       │
│ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ str         ┆ str     ┆ str       │
╞═════════════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ id1_COUNTRY ┆ COUNTRY ┆ id1_other │
│ id2_NAME    ┆ NAME    ┆ id2_other │
└─────────────┴─────────┴───────────┘


strip_suffix solves the issue perfectly, thanks!
On a side note, fot a big dataframe replace_many crashed.

The first obvious thing to try is .str.replace but it only works if the pattern is the same length. Since you just want to get rid of that string and since, at least in this example, the substring you want to get rid of comes after the thing you want to keep, you can use .str.split() and then .list.first()
(
    pl.DataFrame(
    {"origin": ["id1_COUNTRY", "id2_NAME"],
     "sub": ["COUNTRY", "NAME"]}
)
    .with_columns(
        out=pl.col('origin')
        .str.split(pl.lit('_')+pl.col('sub')).list.first()
        )
    )
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────┬─────────┬─────┐
│ origin      ┆ sub     ┆ out │
│ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ --- │
│ str         ┆ str     ┆ str │
╞═════════════╪═════════╪═════╡
│ id1_COUNTRY ┆ COUNTRY ┆ id1 │
│ id2_NAME    ┆ NAME    ┆ id2 │
└─────────────┴─────────┴─────┘

Of course, in this case, you could just split by the _.
